# Automate procedures SQL

Tags: sql

What is an automated procedure in SQL exactly? I was asked about them in an interview and I am not familiar with them. Would they be similar to a trigger?

Comment: I would assume that they were talking about scheduling a job that executed the procedure

Comment: Any specific RDBMS?

Comment: What was the question exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server has the ability to run some SQL code at a specific time(s)/increments

Here is a great informational website on it:
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/setting-up-your-sql-server-agent-correctly/

Officially from Microsoft.
For more information on that:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187061.aspx

If you want to set one up, you need to be sysadmin:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you talk about an automated procedure in a general sense, you're talking about a list of tasks that are performed without user interaction. In a database context, an automated procedure is a list of instructions that are executed automatically without you having to write them one after another.

Now, let's be specific (I work with MySQL, so I'll use its nomenclature):

A **stored procedure** is a list of instructions that are executed as a unit with a single call. An example would be:

```
delimiter $$
create procedure HelloWorld()
begin
    select 'Hello world';
end $$
delimiter ;
```

The above procedure can be called with a single instruction:

```
call HelloWorld();
+-------------+
| Hello World |
+-------------+
| Hello World |
+-------------+
```

This is quite simple, but you can do all kind of things with a stored procedure. For example:

```
delimiter $$
create procedure CloseTheDay(d date)
begin
    declare debits, credits decimal(18,6);
    select sum(debit), sum(credit)
    into debits, credits
    from tranasctions as t
    where t.date < date_add(d, interval +1 day);

    select 'Total', debits, credits;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

You can have control flow statements, you can hanlde data with cursors, you can insert or delete data... you can do almost anything with a stored procedure. In that sense, this is an automated procedure.

If you want to add the requirement that the user is not needed to even call the procedure, you can call it from

- A trigger, that fires up when you insert or delete data
- The event scheduler, where you can configure at which date and time will the procedure will be called

Hope this helps